# Checking compilation error for Scala macros with scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest, scala-macros

Is any more graceful way to test compilation error that produced by Scala-macros than pasted bellow?

```
  assert(intercept[TestFailedException](assertCompiles {
    """case class DuplicatedNamed(@named("x") @named("y") z: Int)
      |JsonCodecMaker.make[DuplicatedNamed](CodecMakerConfig())""".stripMargin
  }).getMessage.contains {
    """Duplicated 'com.github.plokhotnyuk.jsoniter_scala.macros.named'
      |defined for 'z' of 'DuplicatedNamed'.""".stripMargin.replace('\n', ' ')
  })
```

Comment: Shapeless provide the `illTyped` macro

Comment: Great hint! Just need to add the following dependency: `"com.chuusai" %% "shapeless" % "2.3.3" % Test`

Comment: Also here is amazing article about testing macros in Scala from Trudy Firestone: https://dzone.com/articles/testing-macros-in-scala

Comment: It is really much better, because `illTyped` tests in compile time!